# Can't store boost::bind functions in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost

I am trying to map some functions using std::bind and std::map

```
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function/function0.hpp>
#include <map>

class Foo {
   public:
     Foo();
     void bar(bool i) {cout << i << endl;}

   private:
     typedef boost::function<void(bool)> Function;
     std::map<int, Function> functionMap;
}

Foo::Foo() {
  functionMap[0] = boost::bind(&Foo::bar, this, _1);
}
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'boost::function< Signature>'

What could the problem be?

Comment: Works perfectly fine http://ideone.com/ofViT8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `<boost/function.hpp>`, then it compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <map>

class Foo {
   public:
     Foo();
     void bar(bool i) {std::cout << i << std::endl;}

   private:
     typedef boost::function<void(bool)> Function;
     std::map<int, Function> functionMap;
};

Foo::Foo() {
  functionMap[0] = boost::bind(&Foo::bar, this, _1);
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae972d9ec99dec11)</kbd>